# CloudFormation Permission Denied for Config Attempting to Invoke Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I am attempting to create a CloudFormation Template which creates an AWS Config rule which will invoke a lambda function but I am having trouble with giving the Config rule permissions invoke the lambda. The name of the config rule is testConfigRule and the name of the lambda it is trying to invoke is testLambda. My AWs::Lambda::Permission looks like this...

```
    "lambdaInvokePermission": {
        "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Permission",
        "Properties": {
            "FunctionName": {
                "Fn::GetAtt": [
                    "testLambda",
                    "Arn"
                ]
            },
            "SourceArn": {
                "Fn::GetAtt": [
                    "testConfigRule",
                    "Arn"
                ]
            },
            "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
            "Principal": "config.amazonaws.com"
        },
        "DependsOn": [
            "testConfigRule"
        ]
    },
```

but I keep get the following error...

```
The AWS Lambda function arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:1234567:function:testLambda cannot be invoked. Check the specified function ARN, and check the function's permissions.
```

If I take out the SourceArn it works but I want to limit the Permission to the one config rule.

Currently, the CFT is...

1. Creating the lambda
2. Creating the Config rule
3. Creating the Permission for the Config rule to invoke the lambda

It seems to fail when it tries to test the Config rule's invoking of the lambda after the Config is created and before the Permission is created so it inevitably fails with the permissions error.

Is there anyway to prevent the testing of the Config rule until after the Permission is created?

Answer (score 1):

You must leave out the SourceArn as you said as it's not meant for all sources, actually only 2 at time of writing (S3 and SES).

As it says [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-permission.html?shortFooter=true)

> This property is not supported by all event sources. For more
>   information, see the SourceAccount parameter for the AddPermission
>   action in the AWS Lambda Developer Guide.

Checking [the api](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_AddPermission.html?shortFooter=true):

> This parameter is used for S3 and SES.

Comment: This is the correct answer, but wanted to chime in to add: It might be a good idea to set SourceAccount to {"Ref": "AWS::AccountId"}, although this depends on whether OP wants to limit access to the account with the config rule.

Comment: Now I double check what the API actually stated and my answer isn't 100% accurate. I mistook SourceArn for SourceAccount. They only wrote about SourceArn meant for S3 buckets, for other resources it's unspecified

Comment: @JeshanBabooa - Yes, that was my confusion. The documentation doesn't explicitly state what resources SourceArn works for, it only mentions S3 and shows an example of how to use it with S3. I guess it doesn't work for Config rules. I would like to have extra granularity in control of what Config rules could invoke the lambda function. I will take John Nicely's advice and limit the invocation of the lambda to the account.